# Showing that the family $(X_n)$ is independent w.r.t. $P$

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

We have a filtration $\mathcal{F}=(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$, and an adapted, real-valued stochastic process $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ on $\mathcal{F}$. For all Borel sets $A\in\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$ and $n\in\Bbb{N}_0$:$$P[X_{n+1}\in A|\mathcal{F}_n]=P[X_{n+1}\in A]\;\; P-\text{a.s.} $$I want to show that the family $(X_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}_0}$ is independent w.r.t. $P$.

Consider
$P(X_{n+1}\in A|\mathcal{F}_n)=E[{1}_A(X_{n+1})|\mathcal{F}_n]$, where $1_A$ is the indicator function.

Let $B\in\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$ be a Borel set and $m\in\Bbb{N}_0$, with $m\leq n$.

Then, knowing that $\sigma(X_m\in B)\subset \mathcal{F}_n$,
$P(X_{n+1}\in A | X_m\in B)=E[1_A(X_{n+1})|X_m\in B]$
$=E[E[1_A(X_{n+1})|\mathcal{F}_n]|X_m\in B]=E[E[1_A(X_{n+1})]|X_m\in B]$
$=E[1_A(X_{n+1})]=P(X_{n+1}\in A)$
$\implies X_{n+1}$ and $X_m$ are independent

Now I can't figure out how this implies that the family $(X_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}_0}$ is independent. Since $m$ is not fixed and smaller than $n+1$ we have that $X_{n+1}$ is independent to any in the family $X_n$, but I am missing the step of how $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $X_{m_1}$ and $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $X_{m_2}$ implies $X_{m_1}$ is independent of $X_{m_2}$.

If anyone could show this, it would be highly appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $B \in \mathcal F_n$ then  $P((X_{n+1}\in A) \cap B)=P(X_{n+1} \in A) P(B)$ for all Borel sets $A$.  This means $X_{n+1}$ is independent of the  sigma field $\mathcal F_n$. This implies that $X_{n+1}$ is indepedent of $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$. Since this holds for each $n$ it follows that $(X_n)$ is independent.